# Attribute routing - Enum not parsed

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to make a route, but it's not working in this case:

If I call:

```
http://mysite.com/api/v1/product/Generic/1A
```

works fine.

If I call:

```
http://mysite.com/api/v1/product?=Generic
```

works too, but when I call:

```
http://mysite.com/api/v1/product/Generic
```

I get this error:

```
{
 "Message":"The request is invalid.",
 "MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'type'
 of non-nullable type 'GType' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage 
 Get(GType)' in 'MySite.ControllersApi.V2.ProductController'. An optional parameter must 
 be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

The code of my route:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
        (
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{type}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, version = "v1", controller = "Product" }
        )
    }
}

public enum GType
{
    Big,
    Small,
    Generic,
}
```

And the Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(GType type)
{
    ...
}

public HttpResponseMessage Get(GType type, string id)
{
    ...
}
```

So, Web API isn't parsing the value in the URL. Did I forget anything?

Comment: What you have posted doesn't make sense. There is no way that your first url would work with the route given. Could you clean up the samples please?

Comment: Your calls still don't make any sense. You have 'api' and '{version}' in your route so your calls should all start with http://mysite.com/api/v1/ ...

Comment: This is just a example, I don't need to put http://mysite.com/api/... This is just a configuration, I can configure my server to run like this: http://api.mysite.com/v1/Products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I have two equals routes, but with diferents parameters name.

```
api/{version}/{controller}/{type}/{id}
```

and

```
api/{version}/{controller}/{id}
```

The second must be the last route declared.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I still can't see how your first url actually works, but the issue with the second url is that you are trying to pass an invalid bit of data as a parameter.

To keep it simple, I'm just going to pretend for a minute that your route definition is this:

```
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{type}/{id}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

If you were to call a GET on this url `http://mysite.com/product/Generic` , then you will get the same error you are running into. This url will resolve a controller of *ProductController*, with a parameter called *type* that will have a value of *Generic*.

However, your `type` parameter has an actual Type of `GType`, which is an enum. Generic is not a valid value for that so an error occurs. It's the same as sending "abcd" as the value for a parameter that is an `int`.

If you tried to call a get to `http://mysite.com/product/Big`, it would work, as it would be able to parse that value (Big) and a member of the `GType` enum.

Comment: I forgot the Generic.

Comment: I made some changes, I think I made this example quickly, but now it´s correct.

Answer (score 0):

The route you show us doesn't remotely match the URLs you're trying to hit. I have a feeling you're looking at the wrong route. Also, shouldn't `"/Product/"` be "`/{controller}/"`?

Oh, and you mis-spelled `routeTamplate`[sic] in the snippet. I assume that was a transcription error -- I'm pretty sure the compiler would bark on that.